# Can my wyrms exist?

Tags: science-based, biology, dragons, low-fantasy

Now, in a science-based Dnd campaign I'm making, the dragons actually go through a larval state. Called wyrms, these gross little guys resemble extremely large maggots, except with a lot more teeth. They see using a form of echolocation, can breath on both land and underwater, and can get to about the size of an elk. They are omnivorous, and they often adapt extremely well to their environment, and this, along with their parents, determines their species. For example, lets come up with two placeholder species. Let's say a wyrm was born on a shoreline to two fire dragons. He is automatically adapted to hot climates, however, since he hunts and forages in and near the sea, he adapts to that too. When he metamorphoses into a dragon, they end up being a geyser dragon, a combination of fire and water. My question is this: is this "hyper adaptation" possible? Do note that this is almost like transitioning between entire different species. For example, most wyrms adapted for warmer climates have skin like sandpaper, a protrusion on their head for digging, a large plate on their back to keep the sun off, and are also typically quite flat. Meanwhile, wyrms adapted for colder climates have adapted with fur and/or feathers, being warmblooded, unlike most wyrms, as well as storing much more fat.

Also, a link to the chatroom concerning this campaign if you want to help me brainstorm: [This is a creative name for a link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121156/the-new-world-project).

Comment: If I remember correctly, Dungeons and Dragons is a fantasy game with lots of magic. In such a world what can exist is only limited by what the Worldbuilder can dream up. If you want dragons like you've described to exist in your world, say that they exist.

Comment: @sphennings I failed to mention that I am completely rewriting the entire set of rules for dnd, and that my campaign is at least somewhat science based.

Comment: @sphennings Really, I just despise handwaving most of the time.

Comment: It's a D&D fantasy setting, you're the game master, what you say is, can they exist within the framework of rules you've imposed on yourself for this particular campaign? well, to start with you've not told us what any of your worlds rules are.so how the ever living frell should we know .. VTC lacking details that would allow any serious attempt at an answer.

Comment: @Pelinore To answer this, I will say that a large gimmick of my campaign is "area magic." Basically, there are different amounts of residual magic in differet areas, as well as magical "dead zones," where any magic is impossible to preform. If the wyrms required magic for their processes, if the area they were in suddenly became a dead zone, guess who would also be dead?

Comment: @Pelinore magic isnt even needed to make a plausible answer to this because we already have many examples on earth of animals with these traits, so dragons having them wouldnt really be very fantastical at all.

Comment: The edit didn't much help, it's no clearer what you are asking as it is couched in multiple questions. We deal with single focused questions as you know. Voting to leave closed. (From review).

Comment: @Draft85 I've removed the extra questions and made the question of adaptation a little clearer. I hope this helps.

Comment: It's not enough to ask "if this thing were put together with genetic engineering is it a plausible organism". Real world organisms had a plausible evolution. Various ecological pressures resulted in a population of them coming to be, and for them to not go extinct. Those aren't plausible organisms.

Answer (score 2):

before i start, what you need to know is that these are not hundreds of different species of dragons, but instead 3 or 4, extremely diverse species. this is important because it makes this significantly easier to explain. your dragons have a much more diverse form of a common trait in ants, polymorphism. this means that a single species can have many different body shapes, sizes, and even biological functions without needing radical genetic changes. a common example is fire ants, who have scouts, small and comparatively shy ants who mainly find food and make "highways" and trails for other ants, nanitics, who are simple and fairly weak ants that act as both scouts and workers, workers, who follow trails laid by scouts, collect food, and take care of other ants, and finally superworkers, who are big and aggressive workers. the form an ant takes is decided not by its genetics like in most vertebrates, but instead by the climate, temperature, light levels, and foods it gets while still a larva. this is basically exactly what you need for your wyrms, but scaled up by an insane amount. (also, traits to expect in these dragons, polymorphism comes with a huge cost of many different forms, but all very specialized for specific features, so expect volcano dwelling dragons that cant handle below room temp, frost dwelling dragons that cant handle above room temp, etc)

Comment: oh and to whoever downvoted, if you could tell me your reasoning for doing so in a comment to help me improve my answer, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: thank you for helping me with the adaptation, but that still doesn't explain the other two parts of the question. I don't mind if you don't, because this is still very helpful, but if you can, I would like to have an answer for the other two parts.

Comment: @TheSophomore all of these traits already exist in ants, so if you assume these dragons fill similar niches to ants (ie complex colonial hunter scavengers) then its all fairly reasonable

Comment: Forgive me if this sounds rude, but ant larvae aren't the size of an elk.

Comment: @TheSophomore: Yes, they are not, and ants are not the size of dragon. But the point of the answer is that animals which exhibit a complex metamorphosis lifecycle exist; species  of animals with multiple wildly different castes (or morphs, or subspecies, depending on the specific species) exist; large animals exist; species with environmentally determined morphs also exist. The conclusion being that everything you want exists in the real world, just not combined in the way you described.

Comment: @AlexP Once again, not to sound rude, but can they even survive? Are they practical?

Comment: Whether they can survive etc. depends on the rest of the world. After all, once upon a time Earth had dragonflies with a 0.7 m (over 2 feet) wingspan; had 3 meters (10 feet) long amphibians weighing up to 90 kg (200 pounds); had 2.6 meters (8.5 feet) long sea scorpions; and so on. If you want those creatures to be part of the ecosystem in your story, then make up a suitable ecosystem.